# Kong Gateway Manager under Docker: how to configure CORS for the console

Tags: configuration, cors, kong

I'm running the Kong image **kong-docker-kong-gateway-docker.bintray.io/kong-enterprise-edition:2.3.2.0-alpine** on Docker.

I initialized the whole environment with these commands:

```
docker network create kong-net
docker run --network=kong-net -it -p 15432:5432 -v kong-datastore:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_DB=api-gw -e POSTGRES_USER=kong -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kongPwd --name kong-db kong-db:1.0
docker run --rm --network=kong-net -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-db" -e "KONG_PG_DATABASE=api-gw"-e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kongPwd" -e "KONG_PASSWORD=abcde12345" kong:1.0 kong migrations bootstrap
docker run --network=kong-net -it -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 -p 8001:8001 -p 8443:8443 -p 8444:8444 -p 8002:8002 -p 8445:8445 -p 8003:8003 -p 8004:8004 -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-db" -e "KONG_PG_DATABASE=api-gw"-e "KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kongPwd" -e "KONG_PASSWORD=01Ko1996" kong:1.0
```

I then managed to add services, routes and plugins from the Manager interface, available at http://localhost:8002

When I attempt to edit a plugin (eg.: try to set it as disabled ["Plugins", select a plugin, click "Edit", turn off the "this plugin is enabled" switch, click "Update" and confirm]), though, my browser (Chrome) reports the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8001/default/services/0978929a-595d-427a-938e-44c29bae4f7d/plugins/cb0e382f-9be3-4a17-bde2-d2dc7c40384a' from origin 'http://localhost:8002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

It looks like the PATCH HTTP verb is denied by CORS policy from the UI interface at localhost:8002 to the API at localhost:8001.

Let me emphasize that this problem does NOT address the configuration of CORS toward a service/route, but only within the Kong Manager.

I already attempted the following:

- Upload a file in the image, named /etc/kong/kong.conf, containing the following configuration:

  ```
   portal_cors_origins = http://localhost:8001, https://localhost:8002, http://localhost:8003, https://localhost:8004
  ```

  Also tried with this:

  ```
   portal_cors_origins = *
  ```
- Launched the container with the following environment variable (in docker-compose's file):

  ```
   KONG_PORTAL_CORS_ORIGINS: http://localhost:8001, https://localhost:8002, http://localhost:8003, https://localhost:8004
  ```

  Also tried with this:

  ```
   KONG_PORTAL_CORS_ORIGINS: "*"
  ```
- Launched the container with the following environment variable (in docker-compose's file):

  ```
   NGINX_PROXY_SET_HEADER: Origin ""
  ```
- Upload a file in the image, named /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf, containing the following configuration (among other ngnix config):

  ```
   server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  localhost;

       #charset koi8-r;

       #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

       location / {
           root   html;
           index  index.html index.htm;
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type';
       }
  ```

How should the Kong Manager be configured to allow CORS and solve this problem?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Willy nope... :-(

Answer (score 1):

You probably already checked the configuration reference : https://docs.konghq.com/enterprise/2.6.x/property-reference/

the portal_XXX settings are used to control dev portal instead of kong manager. Try change this 2 properties in /etc/kong/kong.conf:

```
admin_gui_url = *
```

and add host name in listen list. For me I'm using web browser on another machine (windows).

```
admin_listen = 127.0.0.1:8001 reuseport backlog=16384, 127.0.0.1:8444 http2 ssl reuseport backlog=16384,{host name}:8001 reuseport backlog=16384
```

Answer (score 0):

setting `admin_gui_url` no longer works in Kong 3.x, it would result in the following error msg:

```
Error: attempt to concatenate field 'authority' (a nil value)
```

Instead, just remove the `admin_gui_url` property helped me get pass the issue.
According to the [comment in config file](https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/c05ce1513a2cea719330513824bc7294afccb611/kong.conf.default#L1933), the CORS header is added only when this property is provided.